# Javascript get time difference between date range

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I can't think of how to solve this. For example:

I have an event which will take place from this date

```
05 June to 07 June and from 15:00 to 17:00
```

Or the end time will be or pass midnight:

```
05 June to 07 June and from 15:00 to 00:00
```

How can i get that this event is in progress for every day in that range? I tried some solution but i always ended up comparing start and end date.

PS. Using native JS.

EDIT: I think i solved it, testing now my code:

```
function getNumbOfDays(start, end){

    var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
    var startDate = new Date(start);

    if(end=== undefined || end === null){
        return true;
    } else {
        var endDate = new Date(end);

        var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((startDate.getTime() - endDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));

        if(diffDays === 0){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}


if(!getNumbOfDays(eventStart, eventEnd)){
    eventStart.setDate(now.getDate());
    if(eventEnd.getDate() === now.getDate()){
        eventEnd.setDate(now.getDate());
     } else {
        eventEnd.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
     }

 }

 return (now > eventStart && now < eventEnd);
```

Comment: Show the code you tried

Comment: What have you tried so far. Are you comparing the current date first to see if that is in range and then checking the time?

Comment: @nothingisnecessary I think i solved the problem, i have updated question with my solution which i'm testing. Take look, maybe you can spot some bug or could be improved.

Comment: @PeterSmith I think i solved the problem, i have updated question with my solution which i'm testing. Take look, maybe you can spot some bug or could be improved.